# Flutter, IOS, App with name __FIRAPP_DEFAULT does not exist

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter

I am new to IOS. I followed the guide and ran the code running on Android on IOS.

But in the log appears

```
021-02-18 13:02:42.035498+0900 Runner[449:77215] Metal API Validation Enabled
2021-02-18 13:02:42.128775+0900 Runner[449:77215] Configuring the default Firebase app...
2021-02-18 13:02:42.129033+0900 Runner[449:77424] 6.33.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000004] App with name __FIRAPP_DEFAULT does not exist.
2021-02-18 13:02:42.132427+0900 Runner[449:77215] Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
2021-02-18 13:02:42.174670+0900 Runner[449:77440] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:51553/bOh9A8fqOm4=/
2021-02-18 13:02:42.506046+0900 Runner[449:77425] 6.33.0 - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS025027] Deferring to Google Analytics for Firebase for event data collection. 
2021-02-18 13:02:42.627177+0900 Runner[449:77215] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process Runner
2021-02-18 13:02:42.627226+0900 Runner[449:77215] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2021-02-18 13:02:42.627266+0900 Runner[449:77215] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2021-02-18 13:02:42.672715+0900 Runner[449:77429] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method addFlags on channel flutter_windowmanager)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:12)
#2      FlutterWindowManager.addFlags (package:flutter_windowmanager/flutter_windowmanager.dart:44:27)
#3      main (package:k_leetory/main.dart:14:30)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:231:25)
#5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
#6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
#7      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1630:10)
#8      runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1618:12)
#9      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:223:5)
#10     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:301:19)
#11     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
2021-02-18 13:05:02.684451+0900 Runner[449:77432] [VERBOSE-2:profiler_metrics_ios.mm(184)] Error retrieving thread information: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
2021-02-18 13:10:21.957514+0900 Runner[449:77432] [VERBOSE-2:profiler_metrics_ios.mm(184)] Error retrieving thread information: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
```

I bother this part "App with name __FIRAPP_DEFAULT does not exist."

GoogleService-info.plist and info.plist are perfect. When I made an ios app in firebase, I couldn't do the same with the flutter package name. Because when setting up the flutter android project. I put it underscore in the name and this worked fine. However, the ios app was made differently because underscore is prohibited when you put the package name.

the weird thing is it is keep showing only white screen

So my question is if android flutter name and ios flutter name are different, will this be a problem in firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes both the package name different in Android & ios will work fine in firebase , because Android and ios will have different GoogleService and GoogleService Info.plist

Comment: do you have any idea with this part? "App with name __FIRAPP_DEFAULT does not exist."

Comment: use com.app.flutterdemo kind of bundle id or package name and other option is you can rename your bundle id